# How to change markdown cell font size Jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have the following markdown cell in jupytre book:

```
***
import action items:
 - item 1
 - item 2
***
```

I would like to increase the font size of the entire cell to make this markdown cell standout between other markdown cells. Is there a way to do that? (I know it is possible to increase the size of a ***single line*** by using ### prefix, but it does not work for the entire cell)

Answer (score 0):

You can have finer control by using HTML in a markdown cell in a Jupyter Notebook:

```
%%HTML
<font size="6">  
    Hello World 
    <ul>
     <li>item 1</li>  
     <li>item 2</li>
    </ul>
</font>
```